# Perl CGI & JavaScript | Select Option troubles

Tags: javascript, perl, cgi

I'm having a tough time trying to figure out why the following code isn't working:

test.cgi:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use CGI;

$cgi = new CGI;
$cgi->autoEscape(undef);
        %ptype = ("0","","1","Pennsylvania","2","New York","3","Ohio");
print   $cgi->header('text/html'),
        $cgi->start_html(-title=>'Test',-script=>[{-type=>'javascript',-src =>'/scripts/test.js'}]),
        $cgi->start_form(-method=>'GET',id=>'frmMain',-name=>'frmMain',-enctype=>'multipart/form-data'),
        $cgi->popup_menu(-style=>'width:200',name=>'ProblemType',-values=>\%ptype,-onChange=>'PopulateSType()',-default=>'0'),
        $cgi->popup_menu(-style=>'width:200',name=>'SubProblemType',-values=>''),
        $cgi->end_form,
        $cgi->end_html();
```

test.js:

```
function PopulateSType() {

   var ProblemList = document.frmMain.ProblemType;
   ClearOptions(document.frmMain.SubProblemType);

   if (ProblemList[ProblemType.selectedIndex].value == "1") {
      AddToOptionList(document.frmMain.SubProblemType, "0", "");
      AddToOptionList(document.frmMain.SubProblemType, "1", "Pittsburgh");
      AddToOptionList(document.frmMain.SubProblemType, "2", "Philadelphia");
      AddToOptionList(document.frmMain.SubProblemType, "3", "Harrisburg");
   }
   if (ProblemList[ProblemType.selectedIndex].value == "2") {
      AddToOptionList(document.frmMain.SubProblemType, "0", "");
      AddToOptionList(document.frmMain.SubProblemType, "1", "New York");
      AddToOptionList(document.frmMain.SubProblemType, "2", "Buffalo");
      AddToOptionList(document.frmMain.SubProblemType, "3", "Middletown");
   }
   if (ProblemList[ProblemType.selectedIndex].value == "3") {
      AddToOptionList(document.frmMain.SubProblemType, "1", "Cleveland");
      AddToOptionList(document.frmMain.SubProblemType, "2", "Cincinatti");
      AddToOptionList(document.frmMain.SubProblemType, "3", "Akron");
   }
}

function ClearOptions(OptionList) {
   for (x = OptionList.length; x >= 0; x = x - 1) {
      OptionList[x] = null;
   }
}

function AddToOptionList(OptionList, OptionValue, OptionText) {
   OptionList[OptionList.length] = new Option(OptionText, OptionValue);
}
```

Sample source output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US"><head><title>Process Alarm</title>
<script language="JavaScript" src="/scripts/test.js" type="javascript"></script>
</head><body><form method="get" action="/cgi-bin/test.cgi/test.cgi?null" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="frmMain" id="frmMain">
<select name="ProblemType" onchange="PopulateSType()" style="width:200">
<option value="1">Pennsylvania</option>
<option value="3">Ohio</option>
<option selected="selected" value="0"></option>
<option value="2">New York</option>
</select><select name="SubProblemType" style="width:200">
<option value=""></option>

</select></form></body></html>
```

Everything looks like it should work find, however when I load the page nothing happens with the second select option button.  It seems hit or miss if the width style applies when the page loads.  I've even tried `window.onload = load;` at the top of test.js. The only thing that I am seeing that may be amiss is perl is formatting onChange as onchange.

The java works fine in regular HTML, it just seems to have issues when trying to implement this in perl. I'm using an example from [here](http://www.petenelson.com/aspwatch/Option%20List%20Examples.htm)

Comment: you say nothing happens with the second select button. i dont see any buttons here. also, what should happen instead of nothing?

Comment: The page will display 2 select option groups (Sorry I said button, but its the select I am referring to).  Based on what you select in the first Select will determine how the second is populated.

http://www.petenelson.com/aspwatch/Option%20List%20Examples.htm

The above link is the site in which I found the javascript, and demonstrates what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="/scripts/test.js" type="javascript">
```

It should be `type="text/javascript"`, the MIME media type for JS that browsers support. `type="javascript"` on its own won't be recognised. (`language="javascript"` is obsolete.)

```
style="width:200"
```

should be `200px`.

```
for (x = OptionList.length; x >= 0; x = x - 1) {
   OptionList[x] = null;
}
```

Not sure `null` is guaranteed to work. The traditional quick idiom is:

```
OptionList.length= 0;
```

Comment: Changing the following line:
$cgi->start_html(-title=>'Test',-script=>[{-type=>'text/javascript',-src =>'/scripts/test.js'}]);

Outputs:

<script language="JavaScript" src="/scripts/test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

The second Select Option still doesn't populate.

the addtion of px fixed the sizing issue though :)

Comment: Still nothing after OptionList.length=0;

Comment: Does Javascript have case sensitivity issues regarding the onChange method?

Comment: Accessed as a property in JavaScript it must be `onchange`, all lower-case. However you only appear to be using the HTML attribute, and HTML is case-insensitive. Another thing: you're using `ProblemType` as a variable in the function, but no such variable is defined. In general, open the JS console (eg. Tools -> JavaScript Console in Firefox) to see what errors scripts are causing.

Comment: Thanks much, with all the suggestions posted I was able to get this running.